# High availability IIS web application, via google cloud storage bucket mounted to windows instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I am looking for a high availability ASP.NET application via Google Compute Engine. I read over the [high availability docs](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps) to look at the basic architecture. All is fine with the grouping of compute engine instances into a load balancer, as well as the SQL architecture, but I'm getting hung up on the high availability of the IIS application.

The desire is to have persistent storage located in the google cloud bucket, abstracting the compute instances from the persistent data, thereby making it easy for the load balancer to spin up more instances if necessary.

The problem is, how do I have the IIS website on each compute instance use the files from the storage bucket. [Google Storage Fuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/) is not written for windows, nor will it mount a storage bucket like a volume which IIS can use. The only alternative I can find is [CloudBerry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/) to mount the volume to a windows server (if it would even work). I'd rather use a google proprietary method though, is there any way to do it with google cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You can now treat Google Cloud Storage like a file system with new PowerShell provider. This feature help you use commands like cd, dir, copy, del, or even cat to navigate and manipulate your data in Cloud Storage. You can refer to [this blogpost](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/10/treat-Google-Cloud-Storage-like-a-file-system-with-our-new-PowerShell-provider.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rclone mount`
https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/

Answered here:
https://serverfault.com/a/1022210