# Google Cloud Storage mount on windows

Tags: windows, mount, google-cloud-storage

I use Google Cloud Storage successfully in Linux for backups. I first mount the storage and then easily copy the files.

Now I want to do the same in windows, but I can't find a way to mount Google Cloud Storage as device.

Comment: Just use the [relevant command-line utility](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) to push backups where you need them. Mounting cloud storage buckets is unreliable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Rclone](https://rclone.org/). Rclone is an open-source command-line program to manage files on cloud storage. It use [WinFsp](http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/) to mount remote drive to Windows.

1. Install Rclone and WinFsp. Remember to add Rclone location to your PATH.
2. Follow the steps [here](https://rclone.org/googlecloudstorage/) to set up your remote GCP bucket. If your GCP bucket use [Uniform bucket-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access), remember to set the `--gcs-bucket-policy-only` option to true when configuring Rclone remote drive.
3. Mount the remote GCP bucket as a local disk

   ```
   rclone mount remote:path/to/files X:
   ```

   where `X:` is an unused drive letter. You can find more details [here](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/).

Comment: I tried `rclone mount` and works fine. However if I add something new in bucket it does not get reflected on my windows. However if I delete from my windows it will reflect in my Google Cloud Storage

Answer (score 3):

There are many 3rd party tools (i.e. [[1]](https://www.gladinet.com/Google-Cloud-Storage/google-cloud-storage-windows-desktop.htm)[[2]](https://www.expandrive.com/docs/map-network-drive/connecting-to-google-cloud-storage/)) that will allow you to mount a bucket and see it as a drive in Windows.  Nevertheless,  [FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) is only available for Linux.  As per the previous comment, if you are only using GCS to store your backups, you can upload them from the disk using [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) or [Cloud Tools for PowerShell](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-powershell/#/google-cloud-storage).

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for that would be to mount it using [FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) into a Linux instance and share it via network Samba/NFS. This would allow you to mount it as a unit in your Windows Machine, even share the bucket with different instances in the network. With this way you could restrict the accesses from Samba, adding an extra layer. Perhaps it’s not optimal but it offers more possibilities.

Comment: hmm, yes this works when I would have a running Linux server somewhere, but I don't.

Comment: You mean you are doing this on-premise? Sorry I thought you were to mean to link a Windows Google Cloud Compute Instance with a Cloud Storage. Perhaps you could install a Virtualbox light machine with linux in your system or do a VPN Tunnel with a Google Cloud Instance and Openvpn.