# Mount a bucket to an instance running Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, fuse

I have to share out ~2TB of files over VPN to endpoints that need SMB access. Rather than creating a ~2TB persistent disk, How could I mount a google cloud storage bucket and share it from my windows server instance? I know in Linux I use FUSE and there are 3rd party apps like TNT-Drive, but is there any suggested or native way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no **direct** way of mounting a GCS bucket to a Windows server.

As mentioned in your message you need to depend upon some third-party tool like [cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en).

I have also found a [similar discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/831179/google-cloud-storage-mount-on-windows?answertab=votes#tab-top) thread, where a community member suggested some other third party software and alternatives for this concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rclone mount`
https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/

Answered here:
https://serverfault.com/a/1022210