# Is there a way to mount my Google Cloud storage account on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2016, google-cloud-storage

I want to be able to host site images on Google Cloud Storage. One way I am thinking to get it does is by adding a drive on my windows server that point to the cloud. Then my site would read the images from the windows drive.

Is there a free way to add Google Cloud Storage on Windows?

I found [ExpanDrive](https://www.expandrive.com/mount-google-drive-as-a-virtual-drive/). But that isn't free. The I found Google FUSE. but that is only for Lunix. Is there a way to mount windows drive directly to my google cloud storage service?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, as of now, there is no Google-provided method to do so.

The only option would be to use the [gsutil rsync command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#using--d-option-with-caution-to-mirror-source-and-destination.). With this command you can mirror the data that a Cloud Storage bucket has into a local directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rclone mount`
https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/

Answered here:
https://serverfault.com/a/1022210